# Is there is a PPA-service equivalent in the Fedora world?

Tags: fedora, packaging, rpm

[For Ubuntu there is this convenient PPA service available](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) where you can get your own package repository.

You can put there source packages which are under an open source license, e.g. development snapshots of your software.

(The server takes care of creating the right binary package and signs it with the repository key.)

Users then only need to add the repository address with one command and can install the packages via apt-get.

Since I am looking into Fedora - is there is something like this available for Fedora packages?

If yes, what architectures/distribution versions are supported? How much space is available?

What is the way to publish packages for multiple rpm distributions via such a service (e.g. current Fedora version and RHEL)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OpenSuse Build Service perhaps?  Don't let the name OpenSuse fool you, it supports other distros as well.  I don't believe it gives you a yum repository, but it does give you a place for users to download your .rpm files.  But the coolest thing it does is it will compile your package for you in whatever architectures and whatever versions of Fedora/Suse/etc you want to support.

Main page: https://build.opensuse.org/
Wiki page: http://en.opensuse.org//openSUSE:Build_Service

Comment: I've heard good things about this service

Comment: The OpenSuse Build Service is awesome! It does give you a yum repository -  or several depending which targets one selects. It even supports .deb based distributions. Even the Ubuntu PPA service does not support Debian distributions and Ubuntu is based on Debian ... I hope Novell keeps this service alive. So far, it works quite well and is convenient to use.

Answer (score 11):

There is [Copr](http://copr.fedoraproject.org/), more information on the [Wiki](https://fedorahosted.org/copr/). You can add a repository with

`dnf copr enable` *user/project*.

(See [here](http://rpm-software-management.github.io/dnf/) for a documentation on Dnf.)

Comment: Update: fedorahosted.org is retired. the new link for COPR wiki is https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Category:Copr

Answer (score 5):

For Fedora their is: http://repos.fedorapeople.org/

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I can think of is [Koji for Fedora package maintainers](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Koji).  If you want to host your own packages, it's pretty trivial to build your own packages locally and put them someplace web accessible.  You can create the yum repository with the `createrepo` tool.  Then you can just create a repo configuration in /etc/yum.repos.d/ that points to that web-based repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo=<URL>
```

Comment: The question is not about how to add an existing repository - it is about how to easily setup a repository containing one/a few packages via an repository providing infrastructure.