# fedora like ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, fedora

I remember ubuntu like a system which had every repository that I could enable and download apps. But now in fedora I can use only her repository and it's all. Do you know if I can change my fedora to be more like ubuntu?

Comment: In other words, you're asking [Is there is a PPA-service equivalent in the Fedora world?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6766/is-there-is-a-ppa-service-equivalent-in-the-fedora-world) (That question is about making one's own packages available, but in the end it's the same thing: you can install from Ubuntu PPAs because people can and do set them up.)

Comment: But how can I add it as a repo? I want to use it by my own software manager.

Comment: If that's your problem, it's not at all apparent in the question you posted. But it's a duplicate too: [How to add a repository on Fedora?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/how-to-add-a-repository-on-fedora)

Comment: I don't quite understand your question: Do you have problems adding repositories or do you have problems finding a repository that has the packages you need?

Comment: ubuntu got skype's repo FFMPEG's repo and so on which he can enable. How can I have such repositories on my fedora. Is there anything to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

you can download rpm from sites like rpmfusion and rpmfind etc.[RPM Fusion Repo](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration)

or repositry information can be manually entered & configured in /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmfusion.repo

once a repo is added to yum, you can enable/disable using "yum --enable-repo" or "yum --disable-repo"

Answer (score 1):

If you are not satisfied with the vanilla version of Fedora, you can try [FusionLinux](http://fusionlinux.org/). 
Its 100% compatible with Fedora and combines free and non-free software to bring the user the most advanced experience on the Linux platform.